# Element's style.backgroundColor doesn't change

Tags: javascript, css

I have got a code for changing the header when search button gets pressed, this part of it works.

```js
function searchButtonAction() {
    if (isSubmit()) {
        document.getElementById('search-box').submit();
    } else {
        showSearch();
        noShowMenuLogo();
        function clf() {
            if (!searchInProgress) {
                noShowSearch(); showMenuLogo();
            } else {
                setTimeout(clf, 25)
            }
        }
        sia = setInterval(() => {
            if (searchInProgress) {
                clearInterval(sia);
                setTimeout(clf, 25);
            }
        }, 25);
    }
}
```

However for some reason when I do this,

```js
function noShowSearch() {
    document.getElementById('search-text').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('search-text').style.width = '';
    document.getElementById('clear-search').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('search-box').style.backgroundColor = 'none';
    document.getElementById('search-box').style.border = 'none';
    document.getElementById('search-box').style.width = '';
    document.getElementById('left-items-box').style.width = '';
}
```

search-box's background-color doesn't change

the result i want:
[image: Search box with a transparent background]

the result i get:[image: Search box with a colored background]

**The solution is at the comments.**

Comment: Please create a complete and working snippet with tools `<>`

Comment: ```background-color: none;``` is an invalid property value. Maybe use: ```document.getElementById('search-box').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';```

Answer (score -1):

`background-color: none;` is an invalid property value. Maybe use: `document.getElementById('search-box').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';`